# No me recorren las imagenes en el arreglo

Tags: javascript

Tengo un arreglo, con imagenes, y grabar ese arreglo con un FOR quiero hacer un slider automatico, que las imagenes cambien solas cada 3segundos, pero lo unico que logro hacer es que se cambie de la imagen 1 a la ultima, sin mostrar las demás , agradezco la ayuda.

```
let imagenes = ['../Iconos e imagenes png/img1.png',
                  '../Iconos e imagenes png/39.png', 
                '../Iconos e imagenes png/img3.png', 
                '../Iconos e imagenes png/img4.png',
                '../Iconos e imagenes png/sol.png'];
let contador = 0;
let imagenn = document.getElementById('imagenn');


carrousel = (direccion) => {
  let direccion1 = direccion;

  if(direccion1 == 'atras'){
      if(contador==0){
        document.getElementById('imagenn').src= imagenes[imagenes.length-1];
        contador++;
      }else if (contador < imagenes.length-1) {
        document.getElementById('imagenn').src= imagenes[imagenes.length-1-contador];
        contador++;   
      }else{
        document.getElementById('imagenn').src= imagenes[0];
        contador =  0;
      }
  }

  if(direccion1 == 'adelante'){
    if(contador == 0 ){
      document.getElementById('imagenn').src= imagenes[0];
      contador++
    }else if(contador < imagenes.length-1){
      document.getElementById('imagenn').src= imagenes[contador];
      contador++;   
    }else{
     document.getElementById('imagenn').src= imagenes[imagenes.length-1];
     contador=0;
    }
  }
}

//automatico = () => {

    for (let i = 0; i < imagenes.length; i++) {
        // setTimeout( ()=> {
             imagenn.src = imagenes[i]
        // },3000);
    }

// }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un bucle infinito que vaya recorriendo en bucle el *array* de imágenes.

El código que tienes

```
for (let i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        // Action
    }, 3000);
}
```

... no hace exactamente lo que pretendes. Itera `times` veces y "activa" el *timeout* para 3 segundos. Pasados 3 segundos se ejecuta `Action`, pero se ejecutan todas las llamadas a la vez. No se esperan una a la otra.

Por ello, deberás hacer código asíncrono que se espere 3 segundos para ejecutar la siguiente iteración.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo

```js
// La función delay devuelve una Promise que
// se resuelve pasados millis milisegundos
const delay = millis => 
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });

// El elemento img no va a cambiar nunca
// por lo que es buena idea cargarlo una sola vez
// en vez de hacerlo cada vez que querramos cambiar
// de imagen (el source)
const img = document.querySelector(`#imagen`);

// La función asyncLoop va a iterar infinitamente
// y espera una función donde se le pasará la imagen
// que se quiere mostrar para cada iteración
const asyncLoop = callback => {
    const images = [
        `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Csharp_Logo.png`,
        `https://cybmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/icon.javascript.png`,
        `https://desophict.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/html5.png`,
        `https://lineadecodigo.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/typescript.png`,
        `https://www.muycomputerpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/stack-overflow-brecha-seguridad.jpg`
    ];
    let index = 0;

    // Esta es la función que retorna
    // donde se va a hacer el loop cada millis milisegundos
    return async millis => {
        while(true) {
            // Delegamos la imagen de la iteración
            callback(images[index]);
            
            // Esperamos millis milisegundos
            await delay(millis);
            // Calculamos el siguiente indice de la iteración
            // cuando llega al máximo (images.length), vuelve a 0
            index = (++index) % images.length;
        }
    }
}

// Definimos la asyncLoop
const work = asyncLoop(image => {
    img.src = image;
});

// Llamamos al loop
work(1000);
```

```css
.image {
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <center> 
        <img id="imagen" class="image"/>
    </center> 
</body>
```

Los comentarios sobre el código están en el mismo.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Diria que hay un fallo de performance grave en tu codigo, pero tuve que analizarlo bien para decir que esto no es cierto, la performance si que es afectada un poco puesto que hay mas llamadas, pero nada en comparación con lo que pensé que afectaría, incluso aprendí algo de esta respuesta. Excelente.

Comment: Hola, @Riven. Me encantaría que me comentaras qué fue lo que pensaste, para tenerlo en cuenta. Quizás tuviera que ver con el bucle infinito, que nunca es algo demasiado agradable de ver, la verdad. Realmente, para hacer una buena implementación, debería usar una función *generator* (aunque implícitamente una función `async` lo sea) para tener un control más acertado sobre las llamadas, pero he considerado que iba a complicar la solución y he preferido hacerlo así. Por otra parte, la "pérdida" de *performance* que se pueda dar con más o menos llamadas a funciones es prácticamente irrelevante.

Comment: Es justo aquello que haz dicho @VRoxa, así mismo lo pensé.

Comment: Madre de Dios, recien empiezo en el mundo del JS y esto hizo explotar mi cabeza, tendre que estudiar mas :c pero muchas gracias por responder!